# How to attach VM to host via NAT?

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware-workstation, nat

I've been given the following instructions but I'm at a loss what I need to do.

"start a VM attached to the host via NAT and connect the VM to one of our servers"

I've been given a copy of VM workstation pro and VirtualBox

I have a basic understanding of computers so would be grateful if advice could be aimed at this level

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In VirtualBox:
Click on "Settings", then "Network" and look for where it says "Attached to:" 
Ensure that you have "NAT" selected.

[image: VirtualBox "Settings" window]

Answer (score 0):

1. Start the VM
2. Set the network mode of the VM as NAT mode meaning that the VM should have a private IP class. Say the host machine has a public IP of type 113.x.x.x, then your VM should have an IP of type of 192.168.x.x
3. You should be able to ping any outside server.